# Assigning a value based on duplicates and lowest price

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the following data:

[image]

What I want to do is create a formula that assigns a value "1" if a number is a duplicate number AND at the same time has the lowest price of all its duplicates. The above data should have another column, so the final result looks like this:

[image]

Is there anyone that can help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be doable with COUNTIFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work

```
=IF(B2=MINIFS(B:B,A:A,A2),1,0)
```

---

If you can work with boolean responses rather `1/0`'s then you can simplify to below such that `FALSE = 0` & `TRUE = 1`

```
=B2=MINIFS(B:B,A:A,A2)
```

Comment: Nice. You can return 1/0 through `=--(B2=MINIFS(B:B,A:A,A2))` btw.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer, it helped! Do you know if it's possible to split the value to 0,5 for each item number if the min value for both is the same?

Answer (score 2):

In Excel2010 you should be able to use:

```
=--(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<"&B2)=0)
```